# How to update columns in a table joined with other tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to update two columns of a table with reference of other tables. While executing the script its showing error.

**Error:** Error starting at line 1 in command:

```
UPDATE wb_costing_work_items,
       sa_sales_documents,
       sa_sales_document_items
   SET cwi_price_per_hour = sdi_price,
       cwi_amount = sdi_price * cwi_hours
 WHERE cwi_lo_id = sad_lo_id
   AND sdi_sad_id = sad_id
   AND sdi_wit_id = cwi_wit_id
   AND cwi_id = 1650833
```

> Error at Command Line:1 Column:28 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00971:
>   missing SET keyword
>   00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword"

**SQL STATEMENT**

```
UPDATE wb_costing_work_items cwi,
       sa_sales_documents sad, 
       sa_sales_document_items sdi
   SET cwi.cwi_price_per_hour = sdi.sdi_price,
       cwi.cwi_amount = sdi.sdi_price * cwi.cwi_hours
 WHERE cwi.cwi_lo_id = sad.sad_lo_id
   AND sdi.sdi_sad_id = sad.sad_id
   AND sdi.sdi_wit_id = cwi.cwi_wit_id
   AND cwi.cwi_id = 1650855
```

Comment: Which of the tables do you want to update?

Comment: I want to update two columns of table wb_costing_work_items the value should come from other table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe.

Note that I had to use some wild guesses about which column belongs to which table as you have not included any information about how your tables are define.

So most probably I didn't get it right and you will need to adjust the query to your actual table structure.

```
merge into wb_costing_work_items  
using 
(
    select cwi.pk_column,  -- don't know what the PK of the wb_costing_work_items is due to lack of information
           sdi.sdi_price,  -- don't know if this column really belong to this table
           sdi.sdi_price * cwi.cwi_hours as total-- again unsure about column names due to lack of information
    FROM wb_costing_work_items cwi
      JOIN sa_sales_documents sad ON sad.sad_lo_id = cwi.cwi_lo_id -- not sure about these, due to lack of information
      JOIN sa_sales_document_items sdi 
        ON sdi.sad_id = sad.sdi_sad_id     -- not sure about these, due to lack of information
       AND sdi.sdi_wit_id = cwi.cwi_wit_id -- not sure about these, due to lack of information

) t ON (t.pk_column = w.pk_column) -- not sure about this, due to lack of information
when matched then 
 update 
    set cwi_price_per_hour = t.sdi_price,
        cwi_amount = t.total;
```

Comment: here alias "w" stand for ?

Answer (score 1):

This should definitely work.

```
            UPDATE (SELECT cwi_price_per_hour,
                           sdi_price,
                           cwi_amount,
                           sdi_price,
                           cwi_hours
                      FROM wb_costing_work_items,
                           sa_sales_documents,
                           sa_sales_document_items
                     WHERE     cwi_lo_id = sad_lo_id
                           AND sdi_sad_id = sad_id
                           AND sdi_wit_id = cwi_wit_id
                           AND cwi_id = 1650833)
               SET cwi_price_per_hour = sdi_price, cwi_amount = sdi_price * cwi_hours
```

Please alias the tables used and prefix columns so one can easily read your query.

Comment: i try to execute the statement it is showing error             Line:12 Column:19
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.